# Cant login to wp-admin (stuck in login form)

Tags: wordpress

This happened since I first installed Wordpress. I have the correct username and password, but when i want to access

```
https://www.example.com/wp-admin
```

that redirect me to

```
https://www.example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
```

and show me a login form like this.

[image]

When I enter a correct username and password, nothing happens. It just stuck in that form again.

I tried to rename plugins directory and create a new one, and also i tried to clear cookies but dont fix anything.

FYI, this is list of plugins that i use on my website

- Akismet Anti-Spam
- Hello Dolly
- Loginizer
- Social Icons Widget by WPZOOM
- WPForms Lite

I am really looking forward for the solution. Thank you.

Comment: did you tried to disable the loginizer plugin, might be it is overriding default wp-admin login

Comment: yeah i did that, and nothing changes.

Comment: switch to twenty sixteen theme or some other theme and check, I think your current theme is overriding the login

Comment: I don't think this is because of the theme I use. Because this problem occurs since the first installation. And I still use the default theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it solved. This is because HTTP authentication because the connection to my site is not private. So if you want to remove that HTTP authentication just add this script to your .htaccess :

```
<filesmatch "wp-login.php">
    Satisfy Any
</filesmatch>
```

But that will make your website not protected from brute force. In case you want to remove HTTP authentication and protected from brute force, you can install Loginizer to your wordpress to limit login attempt.